# How to fix light blue areas in face orientation mode

Tags: faces

I have a problem with a scan from sketchfab. In the faceorientation view there are slightly blue areas that later appear black in the texture when importing to UE. What do these slightly blue areas mean and how can they be resolved?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Those "areas" are actually not areas but edges marked "sharp". you can select everything in *Edit Mode*, right click, and click on *Clear Sharp*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is more of a vertex weight issue than it is face. As it seems the lighter colors are more centralized around a particular vertex. Have you tried clearing the custom split normal data (pictured)? Or joining any overlapping vertices?

[image: custom split normal data]